# How to automatically resize a div based on background image size?

Tags: html, css, image, background

I need help resizing my div.

What I need is simple: I have a image which has 1920x1080px, I put this image as background-image in my div.

My code:

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/Estilo.css"/>
<head>
    <title>ooOOOoos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id=imgHeader>
    <p>Hey!!</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#imgHeader{
    background: url(../_img/img1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

I need something like this:
[image]
But.. I got this:
[image]
Any idea on how to help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to absolutely position the div with the background image. Then you can set it to stretch the entire width and height.

```
#imgHeader{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;

    background: url(../_img/img1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/a3d90gj9/)

*Edit based on comments from OP*

If a fixed height header is what you are looking to achieve then you can set a `min-height` on it:

```
#imgHeader{
        min-height: 80rem;

        background: url(../_img/img1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
        background-size: cover;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -ms-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
    }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/c63b3jme/)

Comment: Works, but with this code, the scroll of the page doesn't apear and I need the scroll

Comment: So you want your page to scroll over the top of it?

Comment: Yea, when I scroll, my page should apear and this div should disappear. Example: [here](http://mobile.thescore.com/about-us/)

Comment: If you want it to be the height of the viewport on load, and then scroll up with the page you will need to use javascript to detect the viewport height, then apply that height to `#imgHeader`.

Comment: So in the example you posted their header is a fixed height. To achieve this you can set a min-height on your `#imgHeader`. I will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

You just need to define a height for the div. I would suggest using 100% like so:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 100%; /*see change here*/
}
#cabecalho {
  height: 100%; /*see change here*/
  background: transparent url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNQ2g.png") no-repeat fixed center center / contain; /*contain will ensure that the entire image is in view*/
}
```

```html
<div id="cabecalho">
  <p>Hey!! Zombie ipsum reversus ab viral inferno, nam rick grimes malum cerebro. De carne lumbering animata corpora quaeritis. Summus brains sit​​, morbo vel maleficia? De apocalypsi gorger omero undead survivor dictum mauris. Hi mindless mortuis soulless creaturas, imo evil stalking monstra adventus resi dentevil vultus comedat cerebella viventium. Qui animated corpse, cricket bat max brucks terribilem incessu zomby. The voodoo sacerdos flesh eater, suscitat mortuos comedere carnem virus. Zonbi tattered for solum oculi eorum defunctis go lum cerebro. Nescio brains an Undead zombies. Sicut malus putrid voodoo horror. Nigh tofth eliv ingdead.

Cum horribilem walking dead resurgere de crazed sepulcris creaturis, zombie sicut de grave feeding iride et serpens. Pestilentia, shaun ofthe dead scythe animated corpses ipsa screams. Pestilentia est plague haec decaying ambulabat mortuos. Sicut zeder apathetic malus voodoo. Aenean a dolor plan et terror soulless vulnerum contagium accedunt, mortui iam vivam unlife. Qui tardius moveri, brid eof reanimator sed in magna copia sint terribiles undeath legionis. Alii missing oculis aliorum sicut serpere crabs nostram. Putridi braindead odores kill and infect, aere implent left four dead.

Lucio fulci tremor est dark vivos magna. Expansis creepy arm yof darkness ulnis witchcraft missing carnem armis Kirkman Moore and Adlard caeruleum in locis. Romero morbo Congress amarus in auras. Nihil horum sagittis tincidunt, zombie slack-jawed gelida survival portenta. The unleashed virus est, et iam zombie mortui ambulabunt super terram. Souless mortuum glassy-eyed oculos attonitos indifferent back zom bieapoc alypse. An hoc dead snow braaaiiiins sociopathic incipere Clairvius Narcisse, an ante? Is bello mundi z?</p>
</div>
```